# Create, display, and save/export a plot/chart with .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, charts, f#, export

I want to create, display, and save/export (to PNG format, for example) a plot/chart in a .NET Core console application. What is the best way to do this?

I've tried `XPlot.Plotly` and `XPlot.GoogleCharts`. I can create charts and display them in the default browser, but cannot save them (programmatically).

With `XPlot.Plotly` I can create a `PlotlyChart` and then get its HTML string with the method `GetHtml`, but I haven't been able to convert it to an image format and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FNU Plot (GNU Plot) has an option to save a file

```
gp.Set(output = Output(Png("test1.png")))
```

For more info see:

http://fsprojects.github.io/FnuPlot/

http://fsprojects.github.io/FnuPlot/tutorial.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However, I'm getting an error when I `dotnet add package FnuPlot`: `Cycle detected. FNUPlot -> FnuPlot (>= 0.1.1-beta)`.

Comment: @CarbonFlambe--ReinstateMonica it's probably best if you clone the source rather than use the package as it hasn't been maintained in a while.   Minor issues you could solve easily with the source at hand.